# TestCafe passed test twice instead of one time

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

TestCafe passed test twice instead of just 1 time

Here's my testcafe config :

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
  .then(tc => {
    testcafe = tc;
    process.env.loginUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/';
    process.env.adminUrl = 'http://localhost:5007/';
    const runner = testcafe.createRunner();
    return runner
      .src('e2e-tests/*.tests.ts')
      .browsers(['chrome'])
      .run({
        stopOnFirstFail: true,
        skipJsErrors: true,
    });
  })
  .then(failedCount => {
    console.log(`Failed tests: ${failedCount}`);
    testcafe.close();
  });
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are no clues why TestCafe passes the test twice. Your TestCafe runner looks correct. If you want the TestCafe team to research your scenario, please create a separate issue on GitHub using the followink link: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md
Please also prepare a reproducible example which we can run on our machines to research the issue.